# I want to write a book, but I don't know if it's "too sexist"

Tags: characters, book

I'm writing a story, and it's like this so far: A boy watches his family get slaughtered before him, he has to become a slave to survive, and then somehow ends up in the position to save a kingdom.

Now, that's not the part I'm worried about. What I'm worried about is if the society (and culture) is too sexist. Here's how it goes:

> (Hierarchy) Fertile women are the most valued, barren women the second most valued, children third, fertile men fourth, and barren men third. Trans people are allowed to transition, but only to a certain point and have a certain role in society. Trans women must wear a band around their arm and are in a social position that is less than children, but higher than fertile males. Trans men are looked down upon even more than a barren male, but hold the same position as an asexual male. Homosexuals can exist, but it depends on your gender for what your social position is. Lesbians are looked upon higher than fertile women or heterosexual women, but gay men are looked down upon more than fertile men, but not as much as barren men (since they can have sex with women, but don't want to). Asexual men are looked down upon more than gay men, but not as much as barren men (due to the fact that they don't want to have sex at all). Girls are seen as higher than boys.
>
> (Values) Fertility, gender, sexuality, birth status, and age are valued very much, depending on which group it is. A fertile person is seen higher than a barren person, a woman is seen higher than a man, a lesbian is seen higher than a heterosexual woman, a heterosexual woman is seen higher than a heterosexual man, a heterosexual man is seen higher than a gay man, a cis woman is seen higher than a trans woman, a trans woman is seen higher than a man, a fertile man is seen higher than a trans man, a trans man is seen higher than a barren man, women are seen higher than children, children are seen higher than men, and so forth.
>
> (Political power and representation) Women are leaders much more often, while men are rarely leaders and sometimes not even allowed to be leaders. Men are common soldiers, or other workers. Women can choose to be common soldiers, but it's looked down upon.
>
> (Child preference) Girls are preferred to boys, and even though there are about 108 boys born for every 100 girls, boys are usually killed off or left to die so that there are about 73 boys for every 100 girls (42.2% of all surviving children). When they grow to the age of 16 (adult in this world), there are about 61 boys for every girl (37.89% of all surviving people at this age). As it people get older, there is a 2% decrease of men each year.
>
> There is also rampant misandry, wars (there is almost never a time when there isn't some sort of war going on), great divide between rich and poor, queen bee syndrome, more violence, and more.

My purpose in writing this is to have a story in which people can see a boy rescue a kingdom, but I also want to show people the effects of misandry and other discrimination without shoving it in people's faces, but still show that it is there. I'm also expierimenting with what a matirarchy would most look like.

My question is, Is it too sexist? If so, in what ways? How can I fix it? Etc.

I know that some people will say that it's too much no matter what, but that's not the point of my question. The point is to see if it's TOO sexist and how to fix that.

Comment: I personally don't think it's too sexist (unless you want to get ugly with misandry), but this looks too convoluted, and an average reader may be detracted by that.

Comment: @Alexander I'm going to hide it a little better, but this is how the society will be structured. I was just wondering if it was too structured. Thanks for your answer! (In the book, the society does get changed some and does end up a little less misandristic, but things take time)

Comment: I think whether this is "too sexist" has almost nothing to do with the structure, rules and customs of your fictional society, and almost everything to do with the way you present it to the reader. There's a big difference between, say, the following example presentations: a) this society is a perfect utopia; b) this society is a reflection of the way real men suffer horribly at the hands of those evil feminist women in our modern world; c) this society is a dystopia which treats some of its citizens horribly based on factors they cannot control, so they need to fight for justice.

Comment: Seems like more of a worldbuilding question so I have nothing to add beyond agreeing with @DM_with_secrets any 'sexism' is in the story you tell. It's pretty standard that any re-imagined society would have flaws otherwise where is the conflict –– except… why are lesbians better than hetero women? Because of male contact and male cooties…? Isn't that contradictory to the whole fertility-thing? I think there are some flaws in your hierarchy, hard to say what angle you're trying for with your setup, but the presumption is it's a dystopia…. It's pretty much always a dystopia.

Comment: @wetcircuit I'm still deciding how the social structure will go (almost done), but the reason why lesbians are seen as higher is because a) they've found a way to get sperm for mothers without having to go through it physically, and b) they are seen as if they've "moved onto higher forms of attraction." Those who are seen as attracted to men are seen as less (since they are attracted  to "the enemy" or "lesser people") while those attracted to women are seen as more (since they are attracted to "the better"). Are there any other points I've missed?

Comment: No, that's pretty much what I assumed.

Comment: @wetcircuit Alright. Just clarifying

Comment: So most women pretend to be lesbian?

Comment: @wetcircuit Some, but not most (about 20 to 40% would or might). It's kind of the same thing with real life, except on a larger scale. There's a thing called "political lesbians" who are women who call theirself lesbian when their actually not. But thanks for bringing that part up, I almost missed it!

Comment: If I'm going to be honest, I have to admit it telegraphs like a sexist strawman argument in the vein of "The Pre-persons" by Philip K Dick..., but I'd wait to hear who the characters are and the main conflict before I committed to criticism. The reason is the focus on fertility-as-value – that is what guys write when they try to write about women… Like giving Black Widow™ a broken vagina instead of a character flaw (or a character). it's a flashing red light (and inherently anti-feminist so it raises lots of worldbuilding questions), but I assume it's intentional to attract a certain reader.

Comment: @wetcircuit This is just the construct of the society, not inherently the characters themselves. Once I delve a little deeper into characters, I'll let you know what I have so far.

Comment: @wetcircuit also, I'm not exactly a feminist

Comment: That's obvious, the worldbuild-y dichotomy is: 'how did the world get to be this way' when it doesn't seem to resemble what women want now (it's not satiric progression of today's world taken to the nth). Again, always the assumption of dystopia, but I don't understand how a society with lesbians at the top hasn't been (re)structured around a lesbian value system. That's why it rings like a strawman argument or a transgressive sex fantasy – both of which are 'allowed' to be as sexist as can be… The only reason to worry about being labeled 'too' sexist is if you want it to be taken seriously.

Comment: It is a bit of a lesbian value system. Those attracted to women are seen as more, and those who are fertile are seen as more (thus fertile lesbians are seen as more than fertile heterosexual women, and fertile heterosexual women are seen as more than barren lesbians). This is not a "transgressive sex fantasy." The reason I have chosen the society as a matriarchy is to play with the idea of matriarchy and what would probably happen (I've done research on both matriarchy and patriarchy). Also, I'm a gay dude. How can lesbians be attractive to me? (Please add anything I missed)

Comment: Weirdly, lesbians enjoy *other* uses for vaginas than making babies. It doesn't matter if you are attractive, this is simply not a lesbian-oriented society. Presumably *any* male (gay or straight) can be hooked up to a machine and 'milked' against his will, the seed can be ceremoniously 'cleansed' to remove male cooties…. If your gynocracy has today's-level of technology, sperm wouldn't be necessary at all when in-vitro and gene-transfer are things that exist now. Artificial insemination and amniocentesis would ensure female-only births. Sorry, but it's a self-breaking world.

Comment: When Margaret Atwood creates a world based on the victimization of women, she has lots of real-life situations to draw from. She exaggerates religious dogma to the *n*th, or she transposes anti-science beliefs from 'backwards' cultures to present-day Western society. She paints a broad brush, but can point to actual things – it's a dystopia with a foundation of truth. Your scenario has *no relation to reality*, there are no gynocracies where fertile lesbians are praised and men shunned. You can write it, of course, but it is a fantasy that sounds like the set up to a sexist strawman argument.

Comment: @wetcircuit It's not that forward in science, just enough that sperm can be taken and put inside a woman to make a child without the parents ever having to come into contact. And I do take things from reality. I'm merely experimenting with a matriarchy, because I have studied matriarchies and this is how it would probably turn out (or something very similar). But I am taking real things from real life. Acts of misandry and stuff are going to come from real things (a few things will be made up to fit in with the story, but the vast majority will be real).

Comment: It's not real, Red Pill. Sorry. The heart of the issue is that you have 2 conflicting tenets: fertility is the best / men are the worst. These things are not separate, they're linked at their fundamental level – no amount of totalitarian brainwashing would make this make sense so the situation is unstable. Some 'revolution' has recently occurred that has twisted society, one belief is being imposed while another is being repressed. There are examples: Zardoz, Star Maidens – both far from reality, lol. Read **Herland** for the saccharine gynocracy (you'll hate it) that's the female paradise.

Comment: @wetcircuit No, I haven't "made it up." For the last time, no. I'm just going to include things FROM real life. And the social structure isn't "unstable," "doesn't make sense," or whatever. I have thought about it, I have researched it, and I have studied it. It works. It's a terrible society, but that's not the point. The matriarchy isn't the point of the story. Matriarchy is a *part* of the story, just not the point.

Comment: 'K, well the question was "Is my story *too* sexist?" and I'm trying to tell you how it's coming across as sexist. I'm not saying "don't write it." You saying it's based on real stuff is not convincing me LOL, but that's unimportant. Just be aware it's also unlikely to convince others…. If coming across as 'not too sexist' is really important to you, I'm letting you know where the problems are. Up to you to worldbuild around it, or hang a lampshade on it.

Comment: @wetcircuit Ok, but just pointing out some parts. Thank you for your feedback, it's been really helpful! And once I write the story, you can check it out yoruself to see if it went well.

Comment: @wetcircuit It looks like a gender-flipped ancient Greece. In a lot of ancient Greek city states (especially Sparta) men mostly wanted to bang other men, but reluctantly had to bang women to keep the population up. Many Spartan traditions related to marriage were intended to ease Spartan males into being comfortable with heterosexuality. That said the amount of detail definitely seems like overkill unless you're writing a parable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that a sexist world is necessarily bad in a book. Margaret Atwood has written books in worlds sexist and otherwise discriminating and gotten praised for it. As long as your character is not a supporter of an this institution - e.g. he feels he should be equal, he has male best friends - or you show that the system does not work, it should not be badly received by a majority of readers.

However, this may not be true. Many people may still find this very sexist and evil. Therefore, I would suggest possibly marginalizing the description of the social position you have here. Ignoring the intricacies - only telling the reader that women are in charge, and that some women are better than others, may allow your readers to ignore the discrimination.

Comment: The point of the story isn't going to be the matriarchy. The matriarchy is going to be a *part* of the story, just not the point. I'm expiriementing with how a matriarchy would most likely look like. It's not going to be that obvious, but people will still be able to tell it. Thanks for your feedback, it really helps!

Comment: "I do not think that a sexist world is necessarily bad in a book. Margaret Atwood has written books in worlds sexist and otherwise discriminating and gotten praised for it." Right, this is the big idea: a book set in a sexist world is a completely different thing from a sexist book.